# simple pointer question ( I don't know why the exact explanation is eluding me)

Tags: c++

This example seems so simple, I don't know why the exact explanation is eluding me..

In the following example:

```
#include <cstdio>

void scan(char* p){
  printf("%c", *p++);
}

int main() {
  char str[] = "hi this is a test";
  char* p = str;

  while(*p != '\0'){
    printf("%c", *p++); //ok..
  // scan(p); //crash
  }

}
```

what is the problem when using the scan function. ie why does p not get incremented in the outer level if that is even the problem?

Comment: When passing a pointer to a function, the value pointed at is passed by reference. The pointer itself is not. `scan`'s `p` is a copy of `main`'s `p`. They both point to the same place, but they are different variables. When `scan`'s `p` is changed, `main`'s `p` is unaffected.

Answer (score 3):

> ie why does p not get incremented in the outer level if that is even the problem?

Your function operates at a copy of that pointer, so the incrementing won't affect the original pointer.

To achieve that pass that pointer variable by reference:

```
void scan(char*& p){
  printf("%c", *p++);
}
```

Here's a [working example online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/107bc38c6ea91f2c).

Answer (score 0):

A copy of `p` is passed, so when you increase it here:

```
printf("%c", *p++);
```

You're not actually increasing the `p` passed in `main`, hence why you get an infinite loop. It works if you don't pass a copy of the pointer, but a reference instead:

```
void scan(char* &p) {
```